# Expanding a function containing a logistic term inside an integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion, perturbation-theory

I am working my way through Mark Homes Introduction to Perturbation Methods by myself. I am having trouble solving problem 1.8(c).

[image]

I believe that I'm supposed to split the integral by introducing a small interval $\delta$, $0 \approx \delta \ll 0.5$ since the term $x(x-1)$ is symmetric about the y-axis at $x=0.5$, reducing the term in the integral to $\frac{1}{\varepsilon - x}$. However, I have the solution from Holmes' public answer sheet and that approach doesn't seem to be part of the solution.

[image]

I believe that the second $dx$ in the equation is a typo, though I have not found the errata for this textbook.

Comment: c. case has a closed form. Making the substitution $x=t+\frac{1}{2}$ 
$$I(\epsilon)=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{dt}{t^2-\frac{1}{4}+\epsilon}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon}}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\bigg(\frac{1}{t-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon}}-\frac{1}{t+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon}}\bigg)dt$$
Evaluating the integrals in the principal value sense, I got
$$I(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon}}\bigg(\ln \epsilon-2\ln\Big(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-4\epsilon}\,\Big)\bigg)$$

Comment: Do you know binomial series? It will expand $(a+b)^r$. If not, you may use $\frac1{a+b}=\frac1{a\left(1+\frac ba\right)}$ and a geometric series.

Comment: @Svyatoslav massive help, thank you